# Scala foreach strange behaviour

Tags: scala

I want to iterate over a list of values using a beautiful one-liner in Scala.

For example, this one works well:

```
scala> val x = List(1,2,3,4)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> x foreach println
1
2
3
4
```

But if I use the placeholder `_`, it gives me an error:

```
scala> x foreach println(_ + 1)
<console>:6: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) =>x$1.$plus(1))
       x foreach println(_ + 1)
                         ^
```

Why is that? Can't compiler infer type here?

Comment: Can you try it with `(_ + [Int] 1)` ?

Comment: `<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '[' found.`

Comment: My Scala sucks, obviously. `(_ + 1:Int)` maybe? I want that 1 to be an Int.

Comment: Oh. You see, the compiler can't infer the placeholder's type. The `_` to be exact. I do believe 1 is Int here.

Comment: Using the extended function syntax seems to work: `x foreach (i => println(i + 1))`.

Comment: Well yeah. But why can't placeholder`s type be infered? I mean, something like `x map (_ + 1)` works without extended syntax.

Comment: Good God, people, that's all according to the specification. There is nothing strange going on here. Just calm down and learn a bit about anonymous functions, `_` as argument placeholder and partial function application. F0RR made a question, it is being answered. No need to inject incorrect information into this.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This:

```
x foreach println(_ + 1)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
x.foreach(println(x$1 => x$1 + 1))
```

There's no indication as to what might be the type of `x$1`, and, to be honest, it doesn't make any sense to print a function.

You obviously (to me) meant to print `x$0 + 1`, where `x$0` would the the parameter passed by `foreach`, instead. But, let's consider this... `foreach` takes, as a parameter, a `Function1[T, Unit]`, where `T` is the type parameter of the list. What you are passing to `foreach` instead is `println(_ + 1)`, which is an expression that returns `Unit`.

If you wrote, instead `x foreach println`, you'd be passing a completely different thing. You'd be passing the function(*) `println`, which takes `Any` and returns `Unit`, fitting, therefore, the requirements of `foreach`.

This gets slightly confused because of the rules of expansion of `_`. It expands to the innermost expression delimiter (parenthesis or curly braces), except if they are in place of a parameter, in which case it means a different thing: partial function application.

To explain this better, look at these examples:

```
def f(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c
val g: Int => Int = f(_, 2, 3) // Partial function application
g(1)
```

Here, we applies the second and third arguments to `f`, and returned a function requiring just the remaining argument. Note that it only worked as is because I indicated the type of `g`, otherwise I'd have to indicate the type of the argument I was not applying. Let's continue:

```
val h: Int => Int = _ + 1 // Anonymous function, expands to (x$1: Int => x$1 + 1)
val i: Int => Int = (_ + 1) // Same thing, because the parenthesis are dropped here
val j: Int => Int = 1 + (_ + 1) // doesn't work, because it expands to 1 + (x$1 => x$1 + 1), so it misses the type of `x$1`
val k: Int => Int = 1 + ((_: Int) + 1) // doesn't work, because it expands to 1 + (x$1: Int => x$1 + 1), so you are adding a function to an `Int`, but this operation doesn't exist
```

Let discuss `k` in more detail, because this is a very important point. Recall that `g` is a function `Int => Int`, right? So, if I were to type `1 + g`, would that make any sense? That's what was done in `k`.

What confuses people is that what they really wanted was:

```
val j: Int => Int = x$1 => 1 + (x$1 + 1)
```

In other words, they want the `x$1` replacing `_` to jump to *outside* the parenthesis, and to the proper place. The problem here is that, while it may seem obvious to them what the proper place is, it is not obvious to the compiler. Consider this example, for instance:

```
def findKeywords(keywords: List[String], sentence: List[String]) = sentence.filter(keywords contains _.map(_.toLowerCase))
```

Now, if we were to expand this to outside the parenthesis, we would get this:

```
def findKeywords(keywords: List[String], sentence: List[String]) = (x$1, x$2) => sentence.filter(keywords contains x$1.map(x$2.toLowerCase))
```

Which is definitely not what we want. **In fact, if the `_` did not get bounded by the innermost expression delimiter, one could never use `_` with nested `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` and `foreach`.**

Now, back to the confusion between anonymous function and partial application, look here:

```
List(1,2,3,4) foreach println(_) // doesn't work
List(1,2,3,4) foreach (println(_)) // works
List(1,2,3,4) foreach (println(_ + 1)) // doesn't work
```

The first line doesn't work because of how operation notation works. Scala just sees that `println` returns `Unit`, which is not what `foreach`expects.

The second line works because the parenthesis let Scala evaluate `println(_)` as a whole. It is a partial function application, so it returns `Any => Unit`, which is acceptable.

The third line doesn't work because `_ + 1` is anonymous function, which you are passing as a parameter to `println`. You are *not* making `println` part of an anonymous function, which is what you wanted.

Finally, what few people expect:

```
List(1,2,3,4) foreach (Console println _ + 1)
```

This works. Why it does is left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

(*) Actually, `println` is a method. When you write `x foreach println`, you are not passing a method, because methods can't be passed. Instead, Scala creates a closure and passes it. It expands like this:

```
x.foreach(new Function1[Any,Unit] { def apply(x$1: Any): Unit = Console.println(x$1) })
```

Comment: I think `Console println _` uses the method `println` as an operator with a lower precedence than the `+` operator. So as a result this is valid `val k: Int => Unit = Console println _ + 1` as anonymous function. `_ + 1` is computed first then passed to `Console.println`.

Answer (score 14):

The underscore is a bit tricky.  According to the spec, the phrase:

```
_ + 1
```

is equivalent to

```
x => x + 1
```

Trying

```
x foreach println (y => y + 1)
```

yields:

```
<console>:6: error: missing parameter type
           x foreach println (y => y + 1)
```

If you add some types in:

```
x foreach( println((y:Int) => y + 1))
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: (Int) => Unit
           x foreach( println((y:Int) => y + 1))
```

The problem is that you are passing an anonymous function to `println` and it's not able to deal with it.  What you really want to do (if you are trying to print the successor to each item in the list) is:

```
x map (_+1) foreach println
```

Comment: OK. So is this kind of behavior a bug?

Comment: @F0RR It is not a bug. It was specified this way.

Answer (score 5):

```
scala> for(x <- List(1,2,3,4)) println(x + 1)
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a strange limitation in Scala for the nesting depth of expressions with underscore. It's well seen on the following example:

```
 scala> List(1) map(1+_)
 res3: List[Int] = List(2)

 scala> Some(1) map (1+(1+_))
 <console>:5: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => 1.+(x$1))
        Some(1) map (1+(1+_))
                     ^
```

Looks like a bug for me.

Comment: Although you mean for `(1+(1+_))` to expand to `(a: Int) => (1 + (1 + a))`, the compiler tries `1 + ((a) => 1 + a))`. This may appear obviously incorrect, but in fact given an implicit conversion on `Int => MyInt` and a function `MyInt#+(a: Any): (Int => Int)`, it is plausible.

Comment: This is not a bug. It is according to specification, and for good reason.

Answer (score -3):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.Beta1-prerelease (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val l1 = List(1, 2, 3)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala>

scala> l1.foreach(println(_))
1
2
3
```