# scala type inference with _ place holder

Tags: scala, type-inference, placeholder

```
List("This","is","Scala").foreach(a => print(a+" "))
```

compiles fine, but

```
List("This","is","Scala").foreach(print(_+" "))
```

fails complaining of missing parameter type. I couldn't figure out why it fails.

EDIT: I meant print not println - not that it makes logical difference.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173373/scala-foreach-strange-behaviour/2176548#2176548 for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that this

```
List("This","is","Scala").foreach(print(_+" "))
```

is not equivalent to

```
List("This","is","Scala").foreach(a => print(a+" "))
```

but to

```
List("This","is","Scala").foreach(print(a => a+" "))
```

Now, let's see the type signature of `foreach`:

```
def foreach [B] (f: (A) ⇒ B) : Unit
```

where `A` is the type parameter of the `List` itself. Since we have a `List[String]`, the compiler knows one has to pass to `foreach` a `Function[String, B]`.

In `a => print(a+" ")` the type of `a` is already known then: `String`.

In `print(a => a+" ")` there is a problem, as `print` is not a `Function`. However, the compiler hasn't considered that yet -- it's still trying to compile `a => a+" "`. So let's look at the type of `Predef.print`:

```
def print (x: Any) : Unit
```

So `a => a+" "` must be of type `Any`, which, of course, means it can be anything. It doesn't help the compiler in asserting what the type of `a` is. Which doesn't really matter, because you didn't want to print a `Function` in first place.

Answer (score 6):

Scala reads `(_+" ")` as `x => x+" "`.  But `println` doesn't contain any type information to help the compiler guess what type `x` might be, so it gives that error.

What you wanted it to do was notice that `println` didn't work and recurse backwards and try it again for `foreach`.  But it can't do that: `println` can take any argument, including a function, so `x => x+" "` is a perfectly valid thing for `println` to try to print.

(And even in a case where it could in theory backtrack, it generally doesn't.)