# Scala closures and underscore (_) symbol

Tags: scala, closures

Why I can write something like this without compilation errors:

```
wordCount foreach(x => println("Word: " + x._1 + ", count: " + x._2)) // wordCount - is Map
```

i.e. I declared the `x` variable.

But I can't use magic `_` symbol in this case:

```
wordCount foreach(println("Word: " + _._1 + ", count: " + _._2)) // wordCount - is
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check [this answer about placeholder syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083523/1180426).

Two underscores mean two consecutive variables, so using `println(_ + _)` is a placeholder equivalent of `(x, y) => println(x + y)`

In first example, you just have a regular `Tuple`, which has accessors for first (`._1`) and second (`._2`) element.

it means that you can't use placeholder syntax when you want to reference only *one* variable multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Every underscore is positional. So your code is desugared to

```
wordCount foreach((x, y) => println("Word: " + x._1 + ", count: " + y._2))
```

Thanks to this, `List(...).reduce(_ + _)` is possible.

Moreover, since [expansion is made relative to the closest paren](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3493141/298389) it actually will look like:

```
wordCount foreach(println((x, y) => "Word: " + x._1 + ", count: " + y._2))
```