# Anonymous function in Scala, error depending on notation

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I'm trying to diff two arrays. Specifically, I have one array with some strings, and another with indices that I want to clean from the first array. At first I tried to use anonymous function annotation with "_", but it didn't work, and I have a hard time understanding why.
Here is an example:

```
val a1 = Array("word1","word2","word3")
val ind = Array(1,2)
val a2 = a1.zip(a1.indices)

val not_working = a2.filterNot( ind.contains(_._2) )

> console>:15: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
> ((x$1) => x$1._2)
>         a2.filterNot( ind.contains(_._2) )
>                                    ^ <console>:15: error: type mismatch; 
> found   : Boolean  required: ((String, Int)) => Boolean
>         a2.filterNot( ind.contains(_._2) )
```

My assumption was that _ corresponds to, for example, ("word1",0) or ("word2",1) tuples. But I don't understand the error, why does it get Boolean type here? I though it would get the second part of the tuple.

Just for the sake of it I tried to rewrite it more explicitly, and it worked. Here is an example that does what I expect, and to my naive eye it looks like the only thing I changed is notation:

```
val working = a2.filterNot( x => ind.contains(x._2) )
```

I'm having hard time understanding the difference between two examples. Why does the second one work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors stacked on top of each other:

```
val not_working = a2.filterNot( ind.contains(_._2) )
```

The first error is `missing parameter type for expanded function`.  Essentially, the `_` syntax can't be used everywhere and this is one of those cases.  (In this case, it's because placeholder syntax can't be used within nested parentheses.

The second error is a result of the compiler not understanding that you were trying to use placeholder syntax, but it still knows that `ind.contains` returns a boolean.  This is indicated in the error message: `found: Boolean`.  The compiler thinks a Boolean value was passed to `filterNot`, but `filterNot` requires a function `T => Boolean`.

Once the syntax issue is fixed, the compiler correctly parses the expression and your example compiles.

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493141/scala-type-inference-with-place-holder) and multiple other places

> The placeholder syntax for anonymous functions replaces the smallest
>   possible containing expression with a function.

So

```
a2.filterNot( ind.contains(_._2) )
```

will be desugared to

```
a2.filterNot( ind.contains(x => x._2) )
```