# Scala map of function using "_"

Tags: scala

Why is it that (in the Scala REPL) I can write, for example,

```
def double(d: Int) = 2*d
(0 until 10).zipWithIndex.map(i => double(i._1))
```

or just

```
(0 until 10).zipWithIndex.map(_._1)
```

yet I can't write

```
(0 until 10).zipWithIndex.map(double(_._1))
```

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1._1) (0 until 10).zipWithIndex.map(double(_._1))
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173373/scala-foreach-strange-behaviour

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scala tries to expand `_._1` *inside* `double`. So, it thinks you want to have

```
(0 until 10).zipWithIndex.map(double(i => i._1))
```

However, it also sees that `i => i._1` does not really fit into one of `double`’s argument types, so it complains and asks you to give a type hint to help the compiler. In this case, though, there cannot be a correct type definition, so the error message is kind of wrong there.