# What operations are performed in bulk when using parallel collections? Strange behavior here

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-collections

Input the following little sequential program and its parallelized version in Scala REPL:

```
/* Activate time measurement in "App" class. Prints [total <X> ms] on exit. */
util.Properties.setProp("scala.time", "true")
/* Define sequential program version. */
object X extends App { for (x <- (1 to 10)) {Thread.sleep(1000);println(x)}}
/* Define parallel program version. Note '.par' selector on Range here. */
object Y extends App { for (y <- (1 to 10).par) {Thread.sleep(1000);println(y)}}
```

Executing X with `X.main(Array.empty)` gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[total 10002ms]
```

Whereas Y with `Y.main(Array.empty)` gives:

```
1
6
2
7
3
8
4
9
10
5
[total 5002ms]
```

So far so good. But what about the following two variations of the program:

```
object X extends App {(1 to 10).foreach{Thread.sleep(1000);println(_)}}
object Y extends App {(1 to 10).par.foreach{Thread.sleep(1000);println(_)}}
```

The give me runtimes of **`[total 1002ms]`** and **`[total 1002ms]`** respectively. **How can this be?**

Comment: Just speculation: since foreach does not return a sensible value, maybe the program quits before all tasks have been executed. Do you get all 10 outputs?

Comment: Yes, I do in the for-comprehension-, as well as in the functional approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This have nothing to do with parallel collections. The problem is hidden in the function literal. You can see it if you let the compiler show the AST (with option `-Xprint:typer`):

```
for (x <- (1 to 10)) {Thread.sleep(1000);println(x)}
```

produces

```
scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(10).foreach[Unit](((x: Int) => {
  java.this.lang.Thread.sleep(1000L);
  scala.this.Predef.println(x)
}))
```

whereas

```
(1 to 10).foreach{Thread.sleep(1000);println(_)}
```

produces

```
scala.this.Predef.intWrapper(1).to(10).foreach[Unit]({
  java.this.lang.Thread.sleep(1000L);
  ((x$1: Int) => scala.this.Predef.println(x$1))
})
```

There is a little difference. If you want the expected result you have to change the foreach-expression to

```
(1 to 10).foreach{x => Thread.sleep(1000);println(x)}
```

But what is the difference? In your code you declare a block to `foreach` and after executing the block it will return the function to execute. Then this returned function is delivered to `foreach` and not the block which contains it.

This mistake is often done. It has to do with the underscore literal. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173373/scala-foreach-strange-behaviour) helps you.

Comment: So never write imperative code in Scala? Who would have thought of this?

Comment: The rules for the underscore literal must be known in order to use it correct. As I said this is not a problem of parallel collections.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insights. Especially the hint about that compiler option was very helpful to see how the expressions get "desugared". I have also read the article you were pointing me to. I read it twice but still having some problems with remembering all these rules.

Comment: Another excellent answer. That German Scala Tutorial must be really good! :-)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Nice to hear that from you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way of thinking about it is that because scala is call-by-value ([Call by name vs call by value in Scala, clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed)) when you hand {Thread.sleep(1000);println(*)} to foreach you evaluate the the block {Thread.sleep(1000);println(*)} only once and hand only the resulting println(_) function to foreach.  When you do foreach(x => Thread.sleep(1000); println(x)) you are handing Thread.sleep(1000) as well as the println(x) into the function foreach.  This is just another way of saying what sschaef already said.