# How to pass a code block to function?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, currying

I am trying to create a **try** clause analogue which repeats code block if exception occurred inside this code block.

```
def retry(attempts: Int)(func: Unit => Unit) {

  var attempt = 0
  while (attempt < attempts) {
    attempt += 1
    try {
      func()
    } catch {
      case _: Throwable =>
    }
  }
  throw new Exception()
}
```

I expect that it can be used like this

```
retry(10) { // I would like to pass this block as function
    val res = someNotReliableOp(); // <- exception may occur here
    print(res)
}
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Operations.scala:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Unit => Unit
    print(res)
         ^
one error found
```

What is the most concise way to pass custom block to my function?

Comment: you dont want a function that returns a unit, you want a unit code block `(func: Unit => Unit)` => `(func: Unit)`

Comment: You do realize that even if you make the changes suggested in the answer that your code will still execute N times regardless of if an exception is thrown or not?

Comment: @aepurniet That wouldn't work, because Scala would evaluate the func and then pass it's result (which we already know is `Unit`). The next time `func` is called it will do nothing, since it's a `Unit`. You need to pass the parameter with a call by name: `=> Unit`

Comment: @cmbaxter of course I missed return after func() call.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to change your method definition a tiny bit:

```
def retry(attempts: Int)(func: => Unit)
```

`Unit => Unit` means: a function that takes a parameter with a type of `Unit` and evaluates to `Unit`.

`=> Unit` means: a function that takes no parameters and evaluates to `Unit`. This is called [call by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed).

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
def retry(attempts: Int)(func: => Unit) {

  for {
    i <- Stream range (0, attempts)
    v = Try (func()) toOption
    if (v == None)
  } ()

}
```

The for comprehension will invoke `func` up to an `attempts` number of times and will stop streaming if the invocation to `func` succeeds, namely if `Try(func) toOption` does not deliver `None`.

For each iteration in the for comprehension, the do-nothing `()` function is called.

If interested in details on each failure for `func`, consider replacing the `Try` in the comprehension with

```
v = Try(func()) match {
  case Success(x) => Some(())
  case Failure(x) => println(x) ; None
}
```

which preserves the semantics initially suggested, yet it extracts information on each failed attempt.