# Scala exception handling using try and recover or toOption

Tags: scala

This is one handler written to recover from exception handling but when i call it doesn't recover but fails for below error message

```
def exphandler(i: Any): Try[Any] = Try(i) recover {
  case e => "Hello"
}


exphandler(BigDecimal(Cols(5))/adjust_currency_map(static(4))), //Open price


======================================
java.lang.NumberFormatException
                                              //|   at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>      (BigDecimal.java:459)
                                              //|   at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:728)
                                              //|   at scala.math.BigDecimal$.exact(BigDecimal.scala:125)
                                              //|   at scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:283)
                                              //|   at com.DC.FTDataParser.FileParser$$anonfun$1.apply(FileParser.scala:115)
```

===============================

Any points will be helpful as it is making me mad.

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `exphandler` is being evaluated before the exception it throws can be caught by `Try`. You can fix this by using a [by-name parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337382/334519):

```
def exphandler(i: => Any): Try[Any] = Try(i) recover {
  case e => "Hello"
}
```

Now the argument to `exphandler` won't be evaluated until inside of the call to `Try`, where the exception will be caught and represented as you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks Travis. It worked but the result is showing as  Success(14.565) not 14.565 as i expected.

Comment: Thanks Travis for the pointer. It worked now.                              def exphandler(i: => Any) = Try(i) match {
    case Success(v) => v
    case Failure(_) => "Hello"
   }

Comment: @user3341078 You can also do: `Try(i).getOrElse("hello")`.

Comment: Thanks Kigyo. I also tried that but it wasn't the problem. Call by value was the issue as pointed out by Travis.