# Calling Super Method in Scala

Tags: scala, specs2

I came across this code when writing test cases in specs2.

```
abstract class WithDbData extends WithApplication {
  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = super.around {
    setupData()
    t
  }

  def setupData() {
    // setup data
  }
}

"Computer model" should {

  "be retrieved by id" in new WithDbData {
    // your test code
  }
  "be retrieved by email" in new WithDbData {
    // your test code
  }
}
```

Here  is the [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2#withapplication).
Please explain how `super.around` works in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `around` method in class `WithApplication` has the following signature:

```
def around[T](t: ⇒ T)(implicit arg0: AsResult[T]): Result
```

Let's ignore the implicit argument, it's not interesting for this explanation.

It takes a [call-by-name parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed) `(t: ⇒ T)`, and in the `around` method of class `WithDbData` it's called with a block, which is the `{ ... }` that's after `super.around`. That block is what's passed as the parameter `t`.

Another simple example to show what you can do with this:

```
// Just using the name 'block' inside the method calls the block
// (that's what 'call-by-name' means)
def repeat(n: Int)(block: => Unit) = for (i <- Range(0, n)) {
  block   // This calls the block
}

// Example usage
repeat(3) {
  println("Hello World")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to Scala and there are very fewer examples and documentations, I have covered most of the documentation and example but I still get confused a lot. Can you recommend me some book?

Comment: A new version of [Programming in Scala](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Updated-2-12/dp/0981531687/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1465222054&sr=1-1&keywords=scala) is out (I've learned Scala a number of years ago from the first edition).