# Scala | operator '=>' and other these types of operator

Tags: scala

can some help me to under stand this code and operator types used or may be used here

```
def times [A](f: =>A): Unit={
def loop(current: Int): Unit=
    if(current > 0){
       f
     loop(current - 1)
    }
loop(x)
}
```

Comment: This isn't an operator. Search for "by-name parameters".

Answer (score 1):

```
def times [A](f: =>A): Unit={ // f is call-by-name argument
def loop(current: Int): Unit // nested function inside of function types
```

This code executes `f` `x` times (i expected this variables to be defined in your code). Basically `f` is a function which will be executed given (`x`) number of times.
To read more about call-by-name: [Call by name vs call by value in Scala, clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed)