# Higher Order Function w/ Call By-Name?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
def higherOrderCallByName(f: => Int => Int, x: Int): Int = f(x)
def higherOrderCallByValue(f: Int => Int, x: Int): Int = f(x)
```

under what circumstances is it idiomatic/proper to use call by-name for a a **function** argument, i.e `f` in `higherOrderCallByName`?

Comment: If for some reason producing the function is an expensive call?

Comment: I don't think this makes any difference as in scala functions are by default call-by-name. Passing function as argument and making it call-by-value doesn't make any difference. I have tested this with a small demo function. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @ManjeetKumar **scala functions are by default call-by-name** can you please support this using an example? I think typically it's by-value. See example below.

Comment: @SudhirSingh : scala functions are by default call-by-value. it's my mistake, i have interchanged the terms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call by name vs call by value in Scala, clarification needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed)

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, in **call-by-value**, the value of the parameter is determined before it is passed to the function, while in **call-by-name** evaluation of the parameter is deferred until it is used inside the function.

I concur with m-z, `higherOrderCallByName` is perfectly valid where passed function can be an expensive call.

Another scenario I can think of is, if passed function has some side effect then by-name parameter will behave differently than by-value parameter. I have modified your example to demonstrate this:

```
def higherOrderCallByName(f: => Int => Int, x: Int): Int = {
  println("Inside by-name function.")
  f(x)
}

def higherOrderCallByValue(f: Int => Int, x: Int): Int = {
  println("Inside by-value function.")
  f(x)
}

def funWithSideEffect() : (Int) => Int = {
  println("Some side effect.") // some side-effect or some expensive call
  x => x + 1    // returns function which increments param
}
```

Now if you call `higherOrderCallByValue(funWithSideEffect(), 2)` output will be:

```
Some side effect.
Inside by-value function.
```

As output suggests, side-effect occurs *before* `higherOrderCallByValue`'s body executes.

Whereas output of `higherOrderCallByName(funWithSideEffect(), 2)` will be like:

```
Inside by-name function.
Some side effect.
```

Where side-effect occurs *inside* `higherOrderCallByName` when `f(x)` is encountered. Now imagine the scenario where `f(x)` is executed multiple times inside `higherOrderCallByName`. Clearly it would have lot of impact in your application.

Comment: So, besides the side effect case, what other reason would a function be "expensive"?

Comment: As mentioned, `funWithSideEffect` can also have some expensive processing going on. Based on this as well you would want to decide if that calculation can be postponed for sometime later.