# Defining variables in scala using def

Tags: scala

In scala def is used to define a method and val, var are used for defining variables.

Consider the following code:

```
scala> def i = 3
i: Int

scala> i.getClass()
res0: Class[Int] = int

scala> val v = 2
v: Int = 2

scala> v.getClass()
res1: Class[Int] = int

scala> println(v)
2

scala> println(i)
3

scala> i+v
res4: Int = 5

scala> def o = () => 2+3
o: () => Int

scala> o.getClass()
res5: Class[_ <: () => Int] = class $$Lambda$1139/1753607449
```

Why does variable definition work using `def`? If it is defining a function that returns an `Int` then why does `getClass` show `Int` instead of a function object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `val` or `var` declaration, `def i = 3` is not variable declaration. You are defining a method/function which returns a constant `3` and `i` does not take any parameters.

declaration using `val` and `var` get evaluated immediately but in case of lazy val and def evaluation happens when called explicitly.

`i` is a not argument function. In order to get rid of confusion you could declare it using empty parenthesis as well

```
def i() = 3
```

Difference between `lazy val` and `def` is

1. lazy val is lazily evaluated and the result is cached. That means further
2. def declaration is evaluated every time you call method name.

Example using Scala REPL

```
scala> lazy val a = { println("a evaluated"); 1}
a: Int = <lazy>

scala> def i = { println("i function evaluated"); 2}
i: Int

scala> a
a evaluated
res0: Int = 1

scala> a
res1: Int = 1

scala> a
res2: Int = 1

scala> i
i function evaluated
res3: Int = 2

scala> i
i function evaluated
res4: Int = 2

scala> i
i function evaluated
res5: Int = 2
```

*Notice that `a` is evaluated only once and further invocations of `a` return the cached result i.e lazy val is evaluated once when it is called and the result is stored forever. So you see println output once*

*Notice function is evaluated every time it is invoked. In this case you see println output every time you invoke the function*

**General Convention**

There's a convention of using an empty parameter list when the method has side effects and leaving them off when its pure.

edited

```
scala> def i = 1
i: Int

scala> :type i
Int

scala> :type i _
() => Int
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But if `def` declares a function or rather creates a function object then why does `getClass` return type `Int`? I would expect to see some kind of function object. For example: lambdas in Java8 implement one of the interfaces under `java.util.function.*` package.

Comment: @KshitizSharma Scala has the uniform access principle, so that clients don't need to know whether they're accessing a field or calling a side-effect-free method.

Comment: True, if you're concerned about the resultant value. But on analysing a function via reflection it should say its a function not an Int.

Comment: @KshitizSharma when you are saying `i.getClass` you are invoking `i` and doing `getClass` on return type which is Int

Comment: `scala> def i = 1
i: Int

scala> :type i
Int

scala> :type i _
() => Int`  @KshitizSharma

Comment: @haskellator Ah! Do you know how I can refer to I without invoking it?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: My answer addresses the question of revision #3.

It is quite useful to look on the code in the middle of the compilation process where you can look on what your code is actually translated to. The following simple program:

```
object TestApp {
    def definedVal = 3
    val valVal = 3
    lazy val lazyValVal = 3

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(definedVal)
        println(valVal)
        println(lazyValVal)
    }
}
```

is translated to the following (using `-Xprint:mixin` compiler option):

```
[[syntax trees at end of                     mixin]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  object TestApp extends Object {
    @volatile private[this] var bitmap$0: Boolean = false;
    private def lazyValVal$lzycompute(): Int = {
      {
        TestApp.this.synchronized({
          if (TestApp.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
            {
              TestApp.this.lazyValVal = 3;
              TestApp.this.bitmap$0 = true;
              ()
            };
          scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
        });
        ()
      };
      TestApp.this.lazyValVal
    };

    def definedVal(): Int = 3;

    private[this] val valVal: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def valVal(): Int = TestApp.this.valVal;

    lazy private[this] var lazyValVal: Int = _;
    <stable> <accessor> lazy def lazyValVal(): Int = if (TestApp.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
      TestApp.this.lazyValVal$lzycompute()
    else
      TestApp.this.lazyValVal;

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(TestApp.this.definedVal()));
      scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(TestApp.this.valVal()));
      scala.this.Predef.println(scala.Int.box(TestApp.this.lazyValVal()))
    };
    def <init>(): TestApp.type = {
      TestApp.super.<init>();
      TestApp.this.valVal = 3;
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

From the output above it is possible to conclude the following:

1. `definedVal` is actually a method.
2. `valVal` is a field which is initialized in the constructor and has an automatically generated accessor.
3. For the lazy field `lazyValVal` compiler generates `compute` method which is called only once when the field is accessed the first time.

Answer (score -1):

There is few different concept. Call by name,  call by value and call by need. All def is essentially calls by name.  What do you mean variable definition using def ??
Looks like duplicate to me:
[Call by name vs call by value in Scala, clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed)
More details in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name

Comment: Call-by-name is a parameter evaluation semantic. Doing what OP does with a `def` happens to behave equally in some scenarios, but should not be confused with it. Also, It is not lazy evaluation. That's yet another thing.

Comment: Oh .. I see, I've mixed "call by name" and "call-by need". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name . However, this is a duplicate question :)