# How does apply() work on a companion object for a trait?

Tags: scala

Consider the below code:

```
object Rough extends App {
  trait Sample

  object Sample {
    def apply[String](body: => String): java.lang.String = {
      "Hello " + body
    }
  }

  val s: String = Sample {
    "World"
  }
  print(s)
}
```

In the code, when I can understand that the apply is being called. But I am not able to understand:

1. What does this syntax mean: `Sample{"World"}`? What is it called as and how does it invoke `apply()`?
2. What does `body: => String` in `apply()` mean? Why does it give me an error if there is no space between `body:` and `=>`?
3. Why does it ask me to type `java.lang.String` as return instead of just `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What does this syntax mean: Sample{"World"}? What is it called as and how does it invoke apply()?**

=> It's `syntactic sugar` where Scala compiler converts `Sample("World")` or `Sample{"World"}` to `Sample.apply("World")` . for eg: when you create a list

```
val list  = List(1,2,3)
```

The compiler actually converts it to `List.apply(1,2,3)`

**What does body: => String in apply() mean? Why does it give me an error if there is no space between body: and =>?**

=> Its an illustration of `call by name` parameter in scala.Here, `body` is a `call by name` parameter. And such parameters have the syntax where you must put a space between `: and =>`. For more information, you could see [call by name Vs call be value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed)

**Why does it ask me to type java.lang.String as return instead of just String?**

=> Firstly, you need to be clear that the `String` in scala is an alias for `java.lang.String`.If you see inside `scala.Predef`, you will find:

```
type String = java.lang.String
```

So, we are actually using the same `java.lang.String` in scala all the time.

Secondly, in your apply method:

```
def apply[String](body: => String)
```

`apply[String]` is not using the `scala String`, its using a `type parameter`. What I mean is you could also write your apply method as:

```
def apply[T](body: => T):java.lang.String
```

And it would work the same way.

Comment: Thanks a ton for giving precise and concise answers to my questions!