# Scala local type inference underscore notation

Tags: scala, compilation, compiler-errors, functional-programming, type-inference

Working through "Functional programming in Scala", I was wondering why the following code gives a missing parameter type error.

Defined is the following tree data structure:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

And the following methods:

```
object Tree {

  def fold[A,B](t: Tree[A])(z: A => B)(f: (B,B) => B): B = t match {
    case Leaf(v) => z(v)
    case Branch(l,r) => f(fold(l)(z)(f), fold(r)(z)(f))   }

  def size2[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = fold(t)((_) => 1)(_ + _ + 1)

  def maximum2(t: Tree[Int]): Int = fold(t)((a) => a)(_ max _)

  def depth2[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = fold(t)((_) => 0)(1 + (_ max _))

}
```

The methods *size2* and *maximum2* compile just fine, but *depth2* does not infer the types on the last function.

Writing the method like:

```
def depth2[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = fold(t)((_) => 0)((a,b) => 1 + (a max b))
```

makes it compile just fine.

Q: Why isn't Scala able to infer the type on the first method with the underscore notation, but is on the second  method? And what makes the other methods compile just fine?

Thanks for your help.

scalac version: 2.11.4

Comment: The accepted answer of [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173373/scala-foreach-strange-behaviour) also answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1 + (_ max _)` expands to `1 + ((a, b) => a max b)` which is adding a function to 1. If you specified types you would get another error:

```
<console>:22: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
(x: Double)Double <and>
(x: Float)Float <and>
(x: Long)Long <and>
(x: Int)Int <and>
(x: Char)Int <and>
(x: Short)Int <and>
(x: Byte)Int <and>
(x: String)String
cannot be applied to ((Int, Int) => Int)
           def depth2[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = fold(t)((_) => 0)(1 + ((_: Int) max (_: Int)))
```

as you noticed, you need to put your params explicitly

```
(a,b) => 1 + (a max b)
```

or skip parens

```
1 + _ max _
```

which you actually can't do here because it would work as if you said

```
(a,b) => (1 + a) max b
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, removing the brackets in the first method, removes any compilation errors, like so:

```
def depth2[A](t: Tree[A]): Int = fold(t)((_) => 0)((a,b) => 1 + a max b)
```

Hence, it seems that the underscore notation always chooses the closest scope for inferring types.