# Scala compiler reports type mismatch for closure

Tags: scala, types, mismatch

I have code below:

```
test("temp") {
    def greeting(func: (String) => Unit, name: String) {
        func(name)
    }

    // Success
    greeting(println(_), "Hello")
    greeting( { case _ => println("" + `_`) },  "Hello")

    // Failed
    greeting(println("" + _), "Hello")
    greeting(println("a"), "Hello")
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error:(52, 29) type mismatch;
     found   : Unit
     required: String => Unit
        greeting(println("" + _), "Hello")

Error:(53, 29) type mismatch;
     found   : Unit
     required: String => Unit
        greeting(println("a"), "Hello")
                        ^
```

I don't understand it very well. What's the different between println("" + _) and (String) => Unit? and why println("a") has not been treated as (String) => Unit also but println(_) does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Statement 1**

```
greeting(println(_), "Hello") // placeholder syntax
```

Above is a short form of function literal called [placeholder syntax](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html). It is expanded like:

```
greeting(x => println(x), "Hello")
```

**Statement 2**

```
greeting( { case _ => println("" + `_`) },  "Hello") // wildcard pattern
```

`case _` is a wild card pattern. You can not use `_` again. If you want to use `case` clause, you should use variable matching:

```
greeting( { case x => println("" + x) },  "Hello")
```

**Statements 3 & 4**

```
greeting(println("" + _), "Hello")
greeting(println("a"), "Hello")
```

*Note* that `"" + _` in `println("" + _)`, itself is an anonymous function. So `println("" + _)` is considered as an expression.

Compiler treats both, `println("" + _)` and `println("a")` as an expression, not as function literal passed as parameter. So it tries to evaluate `println("" + _)` and `println("a")` first, then passes result (`Unit`) to `greeting`, hence compilation error.

Comment: Thank you Sudhir, does that mean compiler put function call priority higher than placeholder syntax?

Comment: Please see my updated answer, it might clear your doubt.

Comment: And how compiler distinguishes a function call or not? as println("" + _) also has "_" inside. why it is not a placeholder syntax?

Comment: Try to run `println("" + _)` in REPL, you will get the answer.

Comment: Sum of all, may I  think when compiler meets underscores, it will always thinks it's owner as a closure? so that it will not be called immediately? coz the underscores is a place which will be filled on the fly? and further, the underscores has it's effective scope which is limited in somehow likes only for {"" + _}, so that function println hasn't been thought as a anonymous function. Am I right?

Comment: Closure is a different concept. Evaluation of `_` is bit interesting in `println("" + _)`. I would recommend you to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173373/scala-foreach-strange-behaviour#answer-2176548